# Oracle DB - Stored Procedure has an invalid number of results

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, nhibernate, oracle10g

I have an enterprise DOT Net application where it can run on both SQL Server and Oracle DB using NHibernate as the ORM. (I don't have an access to NHibernate Model)

Everything works perfectly using SQL Server as the backend, However, when I try to insert into Oracle Database, I get an error saying "**XXX_SP has an invalid number of results in method Save**"

The **save** method is located in NHibernate Model.

I have tried comparing the table schema, and the stored procedure and everything look correct.

I understand my question is not  in details, and **my question is what might be the issue or How can I debug this issue further? Does it make sense to debug the Stored Procedure in Oracle to find more clues?**

P.S I am Super new with Oracle Database.

Comment: Can you give error number?

Comment: It's a custom error not system generated error. Search in Store procedure when this error is raised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your SQL Server has some identity column which you are not using in your insert statement, but when you are using it in oracle you are not providing that identity column which might be a primary key.
You have not provided any details so just assuming that this can be the error.